# Restrict access to Generic views

Tags: django, create-view

i've a creteView (a generic view then) that creates a form where user can put data and create new object.

now, i would like to limit the access to this page only when a function of mine returns true.
This function does not takes into consideration the user, so decorator on user permission would not work.
the function

```
is_allowed()
```

does some logic on the day and time of the day.

how can i restrict the generic view on this function? where should i put the control?

for a normal view it's easy:

```
if is_allowed():
```

so what i thought was to do something like this (where View1 is the creteView)

```
def Home(request):
    if is_allowed():
        return View1.as_view()
```

doing so i receive this message

```
'function' object has no attribute 'has_header'
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's documentation on [decorating generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views).

You can also override various functions from the View base classes to add your checks. For example, you might override [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#simple-generic-views).

Comment: i'm trying to override dispatch, i tried out this inside my GenericView
    `def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Http404`
just to be sure of a Http404. nothing change.

Comment: my fault, i wrote that in the wrong view. now it works. thanks

Comment: You're supposed to `raise Http404`, not return it, but otherwise I'm not sure why that didn't work for you. You might need to quote more context of what you tried up in your question.

Comment: one thing, how can i access the request in the dispatch? i need to check if there's a value in the session.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe it's `self.request`. There's also `self.args` and `self.kwargs` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: self.request seems to not be there. how can i take out the request from args?

Comment: If you're overriding dispatch, then for one thing, you have the request as a parameter there; for another, make sure you're calling the superclass' implementation of dispatch as well. That's what sets self.request and the others. Look carefully at both links in my answer and I hope you'll get enough information to put this together.